# using sed remove the pattern lines

Tags: sed

Can anyone help me solve this problem.

If the PATTERN starting and ending in the same line.
Remove the line including the PATTERN

```
joey people PATTERN  we just had
PATTERN a lot of fun PATTERN
at my wedding
We will PATTERN
have more
PATTERN fun tomorrow PATTERN
all are welcome.
```

The above line should be like this after executing.

```
joey people PATTERN  we just had
at my wedding
We will PATTERN
have more
all are welcome
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: `grep -v 'PATTERN.*PATTERN'` something like this ?

Comment: I have tried \sed '/<PATTERN>/{n;/<PATTERN>/d}' pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ***sed*** approach:

```
sed '/^PATTERN\(.*PATTERN\)*$/d' file
```

`^` and `$` - anchors, point to the start and end of the string respectively

`^PATTERN\(.*PATTERN\)*$` - will match all lines which start and end(provided by optional capturing group `\(.*PATTERN\)*`) with `PATTERN` or contains `PATTERN` as a single word

---

An alternative using ***grep*** tool:

```
grep -v '^PATTERN\(.*PATTERN\)*$' file
```

`-v` (`--invert-match`) option, Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

Comment: What about the line containing only `PATTERN` and nothing else?

Comment: This will delete lines beginning with `PATTERN`  and contain zero or more strings ending in `PATTERN` followed by the end-of-line. I think what was required was a line beginning with and ending with `PATTERN` e.g. `sed '/^\(PATTERN\).*\1$/d' file`

Comment: @potong, this `sed '/^\(PATTERN\).*\1$/d' file` won't delete the line that contains only `PATTERN` (as @choroba mentioned)

Comment: The OP said "_If the PATTERN **starting** and **ending** in the same line. Remove the line including the PATTERN_"

Comment: @potong, it seems like I have two provocateurs here